# Which construction is more cormmon?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, speech

I know my question may seem silly to native speakers, but l am really interested in knowing which construction is more common in everyday speech:

- He is married and has two sons.
- He is married, with two sons.

Thanks

Comment: Hi there!  Your question is better suited to our beginner/novice site [English Language Learners.] [1].  Follow the link and ask your question there, not forgetting to shut down this question beforehand.  [1]: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I doubt either is *more common*, particularly since they can actually mean different things. Somebody who has *four* sons could be described as *married with two sons*, if only two of his sons come from his current marriage . . .

Comment: In everyday speech we typically use contractions whenever possible.  Also 'boys' is probably more common than 'sons'

Answer (score 2):

The question is which is more common:
I would say, "He is married with two sons" is common because the context is informal and casual often spoken between friends, family and acquaintances in a nonchalant manner.

The latter, "He is married and has two sons" is more factual and formal like a report.

I do agree with Jim that the word "boys" (or girls) would used more often in casual conservations, than not.
For example: He is married with two boys living at home.

Comment: l appreciate your answer. It's very clear now.